# In R with mongolite, how to return _id and extract timestamp from _id

Tags: r, mongodb, objectid, mongolite

We have the following R code which fetches an entire collection from our mongodb cluster

```
mongo_uri <- "mongodb+srv://username:password@our-cluster.dwxnd.gcp.mongodb.net/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
con <- mongolite::mongo('users', db = 'dbname', url = mongo_uri)
users <- con$find('{}')
```

In the following code, the `_id` is not returned. However, we want the `_id` returned, and then we want to use the `_id` along with the [ObjectId.getTimestamp](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/) function to extract the date that the document was added to the collection.

Is this possible to do in R with `mongolite`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this one on my own.

```
users <- con$find('{}', fields = '{}')
oid_to_timestamp(users$`_id`[1])
```